# Integrated Circuit Epoxy Outer Molding

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, circuit-protection

I'd like to know whether flame retardant epoxy resins, the FR-4 brominated type for instance, are used in the outer molding for integrated circuits or whether it's just a plain epoxy resin. Additionally, if anyone can direct me to any literature or textbooks that rigorously cover materials of construction for circuit boards I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have a look at this [2003 news blurb about a molding epoxy made by Henkel](https://www.adhesivesmag.com/articles/83521-henkel-loctite-corp-epoxy-molding-compound), whois a major manufacturer of these types of resins.  Perhaps you can find datasheets on Henkel's site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ICs use some kind of high temperature plastic, that survives 205C reflow soldering.  It melts when touched long enough by a hot soldering iron,  like 425F - which does not bother the solder mask, the copper on the PCB, or the PCB material itself.  I read a couple of Texas Instruments datasheets and didn't see anything on the IC body material, just "lead free" and "Green" notes, see [page 3](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4049.pdf)

> Pb-Free (RoHS): TI's terms "Lead-Free" or "Pb-Free" mean semiconductor products that are compatible with the current RoHS requirements for all 6 substances, including the requirement that
>   lead not exceed 0.1% by weight in homogeneous materials. Where designed to be soldered at high temperatures, TI Pb-Free products are suitable for use in specified lead-free processes.
>
> Pb-Free (RoHS Exempt): This component has a RoHS exemption for either 1) lead-based flip-chip solder bumps used between the die and package, or 2) lead-based die adhesive used between
>   the die and leadframe. The component is otherwise considered Pb-Free (RoHS compatible) as defined above.
>
> Green (RoHS & no Sb/Br): TI defines "Green" to mean Pb-Free (RoHS compatible), and free of Bromine (Br) and Antimony (Sb) based flame retardants (Br or Sb do not exceed 0.1% by weight
>   in homogeneous material)

Comment: No, it is actually epoxy. Although epoxy is technically polymer, which is often called "plastic"